# Can Nissuin be done before kiddushin

Tags: halacha, marriage, wedding, kiddushin-eirusin, even-haezer

According to Halacha, is it permitted for Jews to do Nissuin  before kiddushin, and if so, when is the Seudat mitzvah? Or no, does kiddushin necessarily have to proceed Nissuin?

Comment: https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=29179

Comment: If badekin is nissuin then apparently yes

Comment: @DoubleAA Why would it be?

Comment: @shmosel https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78014/whats-the-point-of-the-bdekin-at-a-chasuna