# Bride wearing a veil during wedding in Halacho

Tags: halacha, marriage

I am curious about the historical origins of brides wearing veils in Halacho. Additionally, I am interested in the earliest documented sources of this custom; and, if available, any notable inquiries and responses (shailos and t'shuvos) pertaining to this matter.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2749

Comment: @Shababnik doesn't the first answer there answer this question?